# Rudeness or Politeness. Choose one

Tags: discussion, tags

This site has a [rudeness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rudeness) tag and a [politeness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness) tag. If you go by the definitions of these words, rudeness is the opposite of politeness, and they need separate tags. But if you look at the questions tagged with [rudeness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rudeness), you'll see that the rudeness questions are about responding to a rude situation politely, or some form of "is x not polite?"

In other words, [rudeness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rudeness) is being used the same way that [politeness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness) is. Could these two tags be made synonyms of one another?

Answer (score 3):

No.

The Tag wiki for [rudeness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rudeness) should be edited to read something along the lines of

> Use for questions about dealing with rude behavior or ascertaining whether something is rude or not. Do not use this tag for questions about how to do something politely/without being rude, instead, use "politeness".

Any questions that do not meet this definition should have the tag removed. If there are no questions that fit this description, the tag can go away until such a time that there is.

Comment: Actually, "being-polite" might be better than "politeness".